# Numbers up to $N$ with small radical

Tags: nt.number-theory

For integer $n>1$ define $q(n)=\frac{\log(\rm{rad}(n))}{\log(n)}$
where $\rm{rad}(n)$ is the radical of $n$, the product of the disctinct
prime factors.

For real $A$ and integer $N$ define $S_{N,A}=\#\{n : 1 < n <N,q(n)\le A\}$.

$s(N,A)=\frac{S_{N,A}}{N}$ and $s^*(N,A)=\frac{\log(S_{N,A})}{\log(N)}$.

Q1. Are there lower bounds for $s(N,A)$ or $s^*(N,A)$?

Q2. Is $s^*(N,1/2) \ge 1/2 +C$ for sufficiently large $N$ and fixed
positive $C$?

$1/2$ is trivial lower bound because of squares.
Limited numerical evidence up to $10^7$ suggests that $s^*(N,1/2) = 0.62\ldots$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be more natural to consider 
$$ 
N(x,y) = \# \{ n\le x: \text{rad}(n) \le y\},
$$ 
and the question is essentially about $N(x,x^{\alpha})$ (with $\alpha =1/2$ in your question 2).   The quantity $N(x,y)$ has been analyzed in detail by [Robert and Tenenbaum](https://perso.univ-st-etienne.fr/rool6510/Nxy.pdf), and this analysis has been used by [Robert, Stewart and Tenenbaum](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Gerald.Tenenbaum/PUBLIC/PPP/abc.pdf) to formulate a refined version of the abc-conjecture.  In the range $y \ge \exp ((\log x)^{\frac 12+\epsilon})$ one has 
$$ 
N(x,y) \sim y F(v), 
$$ 
where $v= \log (x/y)$, and 
$$ 
F(v) = \exp\Big( \sqrt{\frac{8v}{\log v}} (1+o(1))\Big). 
$$ 
(These are rough versions of more precise results from the cited papers.)  In particular one has 
$$ 
N(x,\sqrt{x}) \sim \sqrt{x} \exp \Big( \sqrt{\frac{4\log x}{\log \log x}}(1+o(1))\Big). 
$$ 
So the limited numerical evidence in question 2 is misleading, and the right exponent there is just $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. Is $s^*(N,A)=A$ for $0 < A < 1$?

Comment: Yes (as $N\to \infty$).