# Is almost every number the sum of two numbers with small radicals?

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, abc-conjecture

Define a set of numbers with small radicals ([A341645](http://oeis.org/A341645) in OEIS) by
$$A_2=\{n\in\mathbb{N} \;|\; \text{rad}(n)^2\le n\}$$

The asymptotic density of $A_2\cap \{1,\dots N\}$ is $\sqrt{N}\times e^{2(1+o(1))\sqrt{\log N / \log \log N}}$, as per Lucia's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/296473).

1. Main question: does the sumset $A=A_2+A_2$ contain all sufficiently large integers? In other words, is $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ finite?

The number of misses is initially large but becomes sparse very rapidly. I didn't find any after $86931723$,  up to $10^9$. $A$ is not in OEIS (its complement is strictly a subset of [A085253](http://oeis.org/A085253) there).

Other questions:

2. for any prime $p$, do the elements not divisible by $p$ have relative asymptotic density $0$ in $A_2$?
3. Computing (up to $10^9$) the subset $B\subset A$ of sums of **coprime** pairs in $A_2$, points to the misses thinning out very slowly (still above $13\%$ near $10^9$). Are there euristic arguments for or against $\mathbb{N}\setminus B$ being finite?

Is anything else known, or worth asking, about $A_2$, $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Definitely $A_2+A_2+A_2$ contains all sufficiently large numbers, since all large enough numbers are a sum of three powerful numbers. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number#Sums_and_differences_of_powerful_numbers) attributes this result to Heath-Brown. They also mention all integers are differences of powerful numbers, so $A_2-A_2=\mathbb Z$.